# Do I have to bind again if reference changed?

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, binding, javabeans

I have a binding

```
org.jdesktop.beansbinding.ELProperty eLProperty = org.jdesktop.beansbinding.ELProperty.create("${catched}");
org.jdesktop.swingbinding.JListBinding jListBinding = org.jdesktop.swingbinding.SwingBindings.createJListBinding(org.jdesktop.beansbinding.AutoBinding.UpdateStrategy.READ_WRITE, messageCatcher1, eLProperty, jList1);
jListBinding.setDetailBinding(org.jdesktop.beansbinding.ELProperty.create("${message}"));
jListBinding.setSourceNullValue("no value");
bindingGroup.addBinding(jListBinding);
```

but during code execution the messageCatcher1 is assigned a new object. In the code I do :

```
setMessageCatcher1( 
    new MessageCatcher(
        new Catcher<Message>()
        {
            Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(getRegexText());
            @Override
                public boolean catchMessage(Message m)
                {
                    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(m.getMessage());
                    return matcher.find();
                }
        },
        md.findBySQL(getSQLText())
    )
);
```

Do I have to bind again if messageCatcher1 is assigned a new object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was doing it wrong.

I had no PropertyChangeSupport in MessageCatcher class.

When I added PropertyChangeSupport, implemented PropertyChangeListener methods, added firePropertyChange methods, changed the creation of method to merely reset it's fields to new values **all worked.**